# Remove _escaped_fragment from URL using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to remove the string "_escaped_fragment=" from a URL in a .htaccess file.  Here's my attempt so far:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}%1 [NC,R=302,L]
```

This ends up being called in an infinite loop.  The captured paramaters in %1 are successfully pasted in, but the _escaped_fragment_ still appears at the end of the URL.  From the access.log:

```
::1 - - [19/Mar/2019:15:11:34 +0000] "GET /definition?_escaped_fragment_=q=retort HTTP/1.1" 302 251
::1 - - [19/Mar/2019:15:11:34 +0000] "GET /definitionq=retort?_escaped_fragment_=q=retort HTTP/1.1" 302 263
::1 - - [19/Mar/2019:15:11:34 +0000] "GET /definitionq=retortq=retort?_escaped_fragment_=q=retort HTTP/1.1" 302 275
::1 - - [19/Mar/2019:15:11:34 +0000] "GET /definitionq=retortq=retortq=retort?_escaped_fragment_=q=retort HTTP/1.1" 302 287
```

How do I prevent the _escaped_fragment_ appearing in the rewritten URL?

Comment: add ? at the end of this line but ,before the flag , RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}%1 [NC,R=302,L] like this   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}%1?  [NC,R=302,L]

Comment: That was it, thanks.  For my use case I needed the ? before the %1 rather than after it.  Feel free to write that up as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad to help , thank you very much :)

Comment: I wonder why you have such strange looking URLs in the first place. This reads as if you are trying to cure the symptom instead of fixing the cause. Rarely a good idea...

Comment: Yeah - it's the old ajax crawling stuff, I'm getting rid of phantomjs.